# pgfplots giving Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to create a simple dot-plot using pgf-plots. When I try to build the file, I get several Missing number, treated as zero errors on the \end{axis} line.

---

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.12}

%opening
\title{}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    mark=*,
    width=10.0cm,
    height=1.0cm,
    axis y line = none,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick={1, 10},
    ymin=0.0,
    ymax=1.5,
    xmin=1.0,
    xmax=10.0, 
    scale only axis
    ]
    \addplot+[scatter,only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
    coordinates {(1, 1) (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 1) (5, 1) (6, 1) (7, 1) (8, 1) (9, 1) (10, 1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Why am I getting the Missing number, treated as zero error?

Also, if anyone knows a better way to make better looking dot plots, I'd love to know.

Thanks a million!

Comment: I don't get exactly that error, but what happens if you remove `scatter src=explicit symbolic`?

Comment: D'oh. That's it. I removed that and it worked. I was copying code from another person's website and didn't know what was required and what wasn't. I'm not even sure what src=explicit symbolic even means.

Thanks a lot, Torbjorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `scatter src=explicit` or `scatter src=explicit symbolic` it is expected that there is a third data point. See the description of the `scatter src` key in the `pgfplots` manual. As you only have x and y coordinates, if you simply remove `scatter src=explicit` the code works.

One use case for `scatter src` is shown below, where the third data point is used to determine the type of marker used. Note the way coordinates are written, `(x,y) [meta]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    mark=*,
    width=10.0cm,
    height=1.0cm,
    axis y line = none,
    axis x line = bottom,
    xtick={1,10},
    ymin=0.0,
    ymax=1.5,
    xmin=1.0,
    xmax=10.0, 
    scale only axis
    ]
    \addplot+[scatter,only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square,red},
        b={mark=*,blue}}
]
  coordinates {
  (1, 1) [a]
  (2, 1) [b]
};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```